# Is there any way of converting milliseconds string to date format recognizable in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm using the kafka sql source connector with debezium to send data to topics, from which I read into my scala streaming code.

Then, it sends the streams into topics. The json data in these topics are read from a mongodb sink connector which inserts the json in its relative mongodb format to mongodb collection. 
The problem is that the source connector treats the date format fields as string milliseconds while sending to topics, but I want to save it in "date" format (say ISO) in mongodb instead of string milliseconds.

I could use SMT `TimestampConverter`, but that requires single fields for each date, which are more than 100 or even more.

Also, If I convert the string `milliseconds("2147483647000")` in my scala streaming into ISO format `2038-01-19T03:14:07Z`, and then pass into the json, the connector doesnt recognize the date format and throws an error that it doesnt allow '-'. Any workaround to this?

Below is a sample scala code i wrote to send a dummy json to a topic through a producer. The sink connector is supposed to read from this topic to save it in a collection, but the connector doesnt permit '-' in the date format

```
 val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
  val props = new Properties
  props.setProperty(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, conf.getString("bootstrap.servers"))
  props.setProperty(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, conf.getString("transactions.application.id"))

  import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig

  props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, classOf[StringSerializer].getName)
  props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, classOf[StringSerializer].getName)

  import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer
  import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord

  val a = 2147483647000L

  val instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(a)
  val json = "{\"id\":0,\"date\":ISODate(\""+instant+"\")}"
  println(json)

  val producer: KafkaProducer[String, String] = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)

  // Create a producer record
  val record: ProducerRecord[String, String] = new ProducerRecord[String, String]("date-topic1", json)
  producer.send(record)
  producer.flush()
```

Below, I also added a small snapshot (only transformations) of the source connector config:

```
transforms=unwrap
transforms.unwrap.type=io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope
transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones=true
transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode=rewrite
transforms.unwrap.drop.deletes=true
```

Comment: Can you share the sample code (concise and modified but containing all details related to just this problem) for your application ?

Comment: 1) Are you sure you even want data from `2038` in the database? 2) The connector shouldn't care about datetime formats, so is the error actually coming from the Mongo client?

Comment: try moment() npm for converting date and try again.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh added the streaming code in the question

Comment: @cricket_007 It reaches the mongo client as milliseconds. I checked by running a consumer for the topic to which the debezium source connector sends data.

Comment: I'm not sure about Mongo. But if you really need to convert kafka data and a Transform doesn't work, then you'll have to use a stream processor like kafka streams or KSQL